# Angular 2: Array declarado con const se modifica

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

tengo el siguiente problema, llevo algunas horas tratando de dar con la respuesta, los pongo en contexto.

Tengo este codigo. en un theme.model.ts

```
 interface spectrum{
   shade: string;
   hex: string;
   contrast: string;
 };


 interface palette {
   colorName: string;
   values: spectrum[];

 };

 interface mono {
   colorName: string;
   hex: string;
 };

 const monos: mono[] = [{
                    colorName: 'Black',
                    hex: '#000000'
                },{
                    colorName: 'White',
                    hex: '#FFFFFF'
                }]; 


 const palettes: palette[] = 
    [

    {
    colorName: 'Red',
    values: [
        { shade: '50' ,   hex: '#FFEBEE'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '100' ,  hex: '#FFCDD2'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '200' ,  hex: '#EF9A9A'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '300' ,  hex: '#E57373'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '400' ,  hex: '#EF5350'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '500' ,  hex: '#F44336'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '600' ,  hex: '#E53935'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '700' ,  hex: '#D32F2F'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '800' ,  hex: '#C62828'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: '900' ,  hex: '#B71C1C'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: 'A100' , hex: '#FF8A80'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: 'A200' , hex: '#FF5252'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: 'A400' , hex: '#FF1744'  , contrast: '#000000' },
        { shade: 'A700' , hex: '#D50000'  , contrast: '#000000' }]
    },
    {
    colorName: 'Pink',
    values: [
        { shade: '50' ,   hex: '#FCE4EC'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '100' ,  hex: '#F8BBD0'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '200' ,  hex: '#F48FB1'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '300' ,  hex: '#F06292'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '400' ,  hex: '#EC407A'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '500' ,  hex: '#E91E63'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '600' ,  hex: '#D81B60'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '700' ,  hex: '#C2185B'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '800' ,  hex: '#AD1457'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: '900' ,  hex: '#880E4F'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: 'A100' , hex: '#FF80AB'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: 'A200' , hex: '#FF4081'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: 'A400' , hex: '#F50057'  , contrast: '#000000'  },
        { shade: 'A700' , hex: '#C51162'  , contrast: '#000000'  }]
    }
    ];
  export { palettes,spectrum, monos, palette };
```

Mi pregunta radica en si hago una asignacion sencilla en un componente(Asuman que el import de el model esta correcta) como esta:

```
 private miArray: palette[] = [];

 miArray = palettes;
```

**Si yo modifico miArray, ¿Porque también palettes se modificara?**
He llegado a pensar una cosa y es que como los array no son de tipo primitivo este tiene referencias al array original en este caso palettes y si modifico miArray claro se modificara palettes.

En dado caso que esto sea cierto, **¿Cual seria la mejor manera de trabajar con esta array como este?**

Es la la única duda que tengo. 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz una copia del Array, utilizando el método [**`slice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3]

var miArray = array.slice()

miArray[0] = 10

console.log('Array Original', array)

console.log('Array Modificado', miArray)
```

**NOTA** Esto solo sirve si se modifican elementos primitivos en el Array, (No los objetos que puedan haber en el Array)

En el siguiente, te propongo un clonado de Objetos y Arrays, mediante funciones recursivas, admitiendo así cualquier nivel de profundidad dentro del Array/Objeto.

Testeado en [**`jsPerf`**](https://jsperf.com/deep-object-clone-joseahr), podemos ver que es mucho más eficiente, que pasándolo a string y volviéndolo a convertir a objeto.

```js
var array = [{a: '1', b: '2', c: [{a : 1, b: 2}]}]

var miArray = cloneArray(array)

miArray[0].a = 10
miArray[0].c[0].a = 10

console.log('Array Original', array)

console.log('Array Modificado', miArray)


function cloneObject(obj) {
  let clone = {}
  for(let prop in obj) {
    let value = obj[prop]
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
      clone[prop] = cloneArray(value)
    } else if(typeof value == 'object') {
      clone[prop] = cloneObject(value)
    } else {
      clone[prop] = value
    }
  }
  return clone
}

function cloneArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    if(Array.isArray(el)) {
      return cloneArray(el)
    } else if(typeof el == 'object') {
      return cloneObject(el)
    }
    return value
  })
}
```

Comment: Me gusto tu respuesta, mas completa, gracias por tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré algo que respalda mi hipotesis: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Y la mejor alternativa que se me ocurrio fue Conviertiendo ese array a string y viceversa, como sigue:

```js
var arr = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}]

var arrString = JSON.stringify(arr);

var arrStringToArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))

console.log('arr (Array):');
console.log(arr);
console.log('arr transformado en string:');
console.log(arrString);
console.log('arr transformado de String a Array:');
console.log(arrStringToArray);
```